# when use vue-cli-service build i got an node error 'Error: write EPIPE'

Tags: node.js, vue.js

i got an node error, the cause is to use jenkins to build the projec.

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:841:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:712:19)
    at callback (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf.dvf/test-deploy/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:32:17)
```

```
+ npm run build

> widsomfarm_admin_v2@0.1.0 build /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir
> vue-cli-service build


-  Building for production...
 WARN  A new version of sass-loader is available. Please upgrade for best experience.
Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! widsomfarm_admin_v2@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the widsomfarm_admin_v2@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /softdata/npm_local_repository/_logs/2022-10-28T09_05_45_429Z-debug.log
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:841:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:712:19)
    at callback (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf.dvf/test-deploy/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:32:17)
    at module.exports (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf.dvf/test-deploy/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:5)
    at handle (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf.dvf/test-deploy/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dvf.dvf/test-deploy/F-adopt-backoffice/codeDir/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:55:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:912:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:845:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
 Shell Script -- npm run build (self time 1min 10s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by not running `npm install` before the `npm run build` in jenkins.

```bash
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Also building with CI/CD tools like Jenkins sometimes requires `npm install` to be replaced with `npm ci` to make sure doing a clean install of your dependencies. More here [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci)

```bash
npm ci
npm run build
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too , but only when run build in server environment.
after search about this problem, i found that it because memory limitation ,but unfortunately i couldn't find the right solution .
Maybe this lead will able to help you